# Is there a name for this synchronization primitive?

Tags: events, synchronization, terminology, semaphore

Suppose I have a synchronization primitive with the following features:

1. It has a *Count* property which is initially zero.
2. It has a *Wait* method. When invoked on an object with *Count* zero, it returns immediately.
   Otherwise, it blocks and waits for the object to be signalled.
3. It has a *Signal* method. When invoked on an object with a positive *Count*, it decrements it and unblocks the current/next invocation of *Wait*.
4. If *Signal* was called 5 times while *Wait* waited, not only will the current *Wait* return, but the next 4 calls to *Wait* will return immediately.
5. It has an *ExpectSignal* (not sure about the name) method. It increments the *Count* property.

Is there a standard, even if obscure, name for such an entity?

Comment: Standard name? I doubt it. But barring point #4, in Java what you described is called a CountDownLatch.

Comment: When will the counter get incremented? Or is it never incremented, only decremented on every call to _Signal_?

Comment: Perception - unfortunately point #4 is critical for me.

Comment: Simon - edited to address your question. The new method, ExpectSignal or something like that, is the only way to increment the counter.